# Recommended ways to secure a webservice?

Tags: java, web-services

Do you know what are the best practices in securing webservices ?

What I need is some security added in the header of the soap message.
(ssl is not an option)

Comment: what do you mean by "_adding security_"?

Comment: What are you trying to protect?  Are you trying to prevent eavesdropping, unauthorized use, privacy violations, data destruction, data theft, ...?

Comment: I want the webservice to be accessed by providing some credentials.

Comment: This means that you do not need to protect the content , only to allow authorized use ?

Comment: These credentials, if an attacker can eavesdrop, can they replay these credentials and get the same access?  If an attacker can observe a response initiated by someone with credentials, do they get the same information/access as if they sent the request?

Comment: @Mike not really cause there username token policy that has a digest expiration time and also a nonce...and servers might be able to detect replay attacks.

Comment: @Cris, "Might be able to detect replay" is not "is secure against replay attack."  How is this nonce used?  Typically, expiration is used to prevent unlimited abuse of stolen credentials.  An expiration time is only protection against replay if the expiration time is short w.r.t. the time it takes to submit a request.  The only solid protection against replay is single-use credentials.

Comment: @Mike The nonce is a combination of created time and credentials hashed.Weblogic supports detection of duplicate nonces.So if somebody sniffed your messages if he takes the header and tries again it should be refused.Evrything is described here http://tinyurl.com/5tufaqm

Comment: @Cris, "created time" == "created time of credentials"?  If so, replay might be stopped, but you still need to make sure that an attacker can't eavesdrop on a response that contains any sensitive info, and that an attacker can't eavesdrop on a request if that request might contain credentials that are threaded through to other systems.  Do your responses contain any sensitive info, and do your requests contain credentials for other systems so that an attacker who reads your requests can turn around and compromise other systems directly.

Comment: @Mike what i described is ok as long as you do not have any sensitive things inside the message and only thing you need is to be authorized to use the webservice.For other type of message level securty is another story...I thought he want only some credentials.

Comment: @Cris, Sorry, I somehow got it through my head that you and user812723 were the same person.  I was trying to draw out the parameters within which to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XML-Encryption defined by W3C to make sure that your WS Messages stay confidential.
Theres also an XML-Signature Standard, also by W3C, which ensures Integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add the

```
X-Magic-Security-Dust: true
```

header to your requests.

Seriously though, read [Bruce Schneier](http://www.zdnet.com/news/schneier-no-magic-security-dust/126510) and maybe repost with clarification.

> **What's going to be different about the state of Internet and network security three years from now?**
>
> I think we're finally past the era where people believe in magic security dust, that all they need to do is buy the right set of products and their network will be imbued with the property of "secure." Security is a process. It's a journey.